# Esperar un Tiempo despues de ejecutar el modal - Jquery

Tags: jquery, funciones, modal

Requiero de su colaboracion para solventar un inconveniente que tengo con respecto al siguiente tema.

Necesito realizar lo siguiente.

Mostrar un modal al ejecutarse una funcion.
Verificar que este activo el Modal.
Al estar activo debo esperar 10 segundos para cargar la nueva informacion

Esta Tarea es ciclica y el problema que tengo es que al utilizar el each me muestra siempre ya el ultimo dato de la cola cuando necesito que cada 10 segundo se muestre uno diferente.

Alguna idea de como puedo resolver lo siguiente....

Tambien tengo una funcion Wait, esta funcion espera el tiempo que le digo, solo que el modal aparece es despues de que esta funcion termina de ejecutarce y necesito que se muestre el modal y luego de eso espere el tiempo que requiero.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Aqui Parte del Codigo.

```
      var time = (50000 / cont);


      $.each(data.info, function(key, item)
      {

        if(item.view == 0)
        {
          $('#tableModal').html('<table class="table table-bordered "border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 11px;"><tbody><tr><td>ID</td><td>' + item['idClient'] + '</td><td>CLIENTE</td><td>' + item['client'] + '</td></tr><tr><td>TICKET</td><td>' + item['ticket'] + '</td><td>VENDEDOR</td><td>' + item['sale'] + '</td></tr></tbody></table>');                   

          var   text = '<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 75px; font-family: serif;">'+item['score']+'</h1>';
          console.log(text);

          $('#showScore').html(text);
          $('#ClousuresInfoModal').modal('show');

          var esVisible = $("#elemento").is(":visible");

          wait(10);

          console.log(esVisible);

          setInterval(function(){
            $("#tableModal").html('');
            $('#ClousuresInfoModal').modal('hide');
          }, 10000);
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tendrias que hacer es una funcion muestre/abra la modal, y esta funcion llamarse a si misma despues del timer.

```
var index = 0;
showModal();

function showModal()
{
   var item = data.info[index];

   if(item.view == 0)
    {
      $('#tableModal').html('<table class="table table-bordered "border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 11px;"><tbody><tr><td>ID</td><td>' + item['idClient'] + '</td><td>CLIENTE</td><td>' + item['client'] + '</td></tr><tr><td>TICKET</td><td>' + item['ticket'] + '</td><td>VENDEDOR</td><td>' + item['sale'] + '</td></tr></tbody></table>');                   

      var   text = '<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 75px; font-family: serif;">'+item['score']+'</h1>';

      $('#showScore').html(text);
      $('#ClousuresInfoModal').modal('show');

      index++;
      if(index<data.info.length) {
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#ClousuresInfoModal').modal('hide');
        showModal();
      }, 10000);
      }
    }

}
```